# same HttpPut request code format not working but the works on another request

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I have a HTTPPUT request that is not being called. I have a similar put request that manages another tab and it works. Both pages are pretty identical. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried almost everything and don't know what else to try.

controller:

```
   [HttpPut]
        [Route("updateAllocations({type})")]
        public IHttpActionResult UpdateAllocations(string type, T_LOC entity)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside");
            _allocationsService.UpdateAllocations(type,entity);
            return Ok();
        }
```

interface:

```
using OTPS.Core.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OTPS.Core.Models;
namespace OTPS.Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAllocationsService
    {

        void UpdateAllocations(string type,  T_LOC entity);
    }
}
```

service:

```
  public void UpdateAllocations(string type, T_LOC entity)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("inside");
        }
```

CLIENT SIDE:

```
 public updateAllocation(type: string , entity) {
        console.log("sdfsdf")
        console.log(`${this.baseUrl}/api/allocations/updateAllocations(${type})`)
        return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/api/allocations/updateAllocations({type})`, entity, { headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true })
            .pipe(catchError((error: Error) => {
                console.log("sdfasd111111sdf")
                return this.errorService.handleError(error);
            }));
    }
```

I am expecting the clinet side to call the put request before making any further logic but the print on server side never gets called..

Comment: Hope you are subscribing to the observable returned from `updateAllocation` in the upper layers of your code [i.e. component/service]?

Comment: @user2216584 i am. its not even printing into the debug for csharp side.

Comment: @user2216584 LOL NVM YOURE RIGHt i didnt call subscribe hehexd thanks so much xd

Comment: It is not necessary to edit your post and add "Solved", as it would invalidate the purpose of Stack Overflow as a question and answer site (it would no longer be a question). If you feel this question warrants a proper answer, you can post one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `subscribe` to the service method inside component:

```
this.myService.updateAllocation(type, entity).subscribe( response => {
// do something here with response

});
```

> You must call `subscribe()` or nothing happens. Just calling
>   Service method does not initiate the PUT/DELETE/POST/GET request.
>
> **Always subscribe!**
>
> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call
>   `subscribe()` on the observable returned by that method. This is true
>   for all `HttpClient` methods.